# Converting string to float issue

Tags: c#

Hello world I have some issue trying to convert string that contains float number (ex. string s = "23.532") to float. Please take a look. Values are taken from .txt file.

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwNz7.jpg)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYUvX.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Chart Properties
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-5, 5);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 1000);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;







            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

        }

        private void BLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load File
            string SingleNumb= "";
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));

                while ((SingleNumb = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    float value = float.Parse(SingleNumb);
                    //MessageBox.Show(value.ToString()); just to correct values
                }


                   //chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Single.Parse(SingleNumb), i++);


                sr.Dispose();
                sr.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

text file

```
0.534
-0.283
4.632
-8.5325
```

Comment: highly recommended to use float.TryParse(string,out float) in these scenarios.

Comment: Probably SingleNumb does not have a valid float. Which is its value when the exception is thrown?

Comment: SingleNumb value is "0.534"

Comment: Please include code as text, not images.

Comment: Included in main post.

Comment: I have tried with your inputs (0.534, -0.283, 4.632, -8.5325) and works fine. Is our text file contains double quotes (")?

Comment: Since you are from Poland you either need to use `,` as decimal separator  or pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `float.Parse` call. Will find dup at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string uses dot (.) as decimal separator, you should use this overload:

```
 float xFreq = Convert.ToSingle(param, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Not really sure, but Additional information looks Slavic to me and the default decimal separator might be comma (,) instead of dot.  Of course, this depends on the culture of the current thread which depends on Regional settings.

Comment: Numbers are separated with dot. Above code returns

Error CS0103 The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @DE4POW This is most likely the answer you are looking for... Not really sure why it was downvoted... (probably someone figured that there are tons "parsing number as float fails in Poland" questions and downvoted for fun)

Comment: Thanks for reply ; )

Comment: @DE4POW - you need to include `System.Globalization` as indicated in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should use [float.TryParse(string, float)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx) because it will test whether the `string` that you want to parse can be converted to a `float` before converting it.

**Try this:**

```
string floatString = "23.532";
float number = 0;
if (float.TryParse(floatString, out number)) Console.WriteLine($"Number = {number}");
```

[float.TryParse(string, float)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx) Method Converts the `string` representation of a number to its single-precision floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed. `true` means succeeded and `false` otherwise.

Comment: You should add some explanation as to why this answer should be used (such as the why TryParse is useful in this case over Parse).

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse` and check the result.

```
float number;

if(float.TryParse(floatString, out number))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update while loop inside the function BLoad_Click(...) as below:

```
while((SingleNumb = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Any;
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    float value = 0.0f;
    if (float.TryParse(SingleNumb, style, culture, out value))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Conversion failed!");
    }
}
```

Note: 'float.TryParse(...)' - Converts the string representation of a number to its floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

Comment: Fails all the time

Comment: What is the value of SingleNumb? Try to debug value of SingleNumb.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really so deep in c# to know how debug yet. Included whole code in main post if u wish to look.

Comment: I have tried with your inputs (0.534, -0.283, 4.632, -8.5325) and works fine. Is your text file contains double quotes (")?

Comment: What is your current culture? Go to control panel and select 'Region and Language', select tab 'Location' and send 'Current location' value.

Comment: I have observed your culture is Polish, please use my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Could you try:**

```
string SingleNumb = "23.532";  
float value = float.Parse(SingleNumb);
```

**Result from conversion:**

[image]

I wonder if the value you're loading from the file is a valid string!

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for the Convert.ToSingle() method:

```
string floatString = "23.532";
float actualFloat = Convert.ToSingle(floatString);
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this....

```
string SingleNumb = "";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\testFile.txt");

// Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.            
foreach (string line in lines)
{
     if((SingleNumb = line) != null)
     {
         float value = float.Parse(SingleNumb);
     }
}
```

(*) create a file "testFile.txt" in C:\ with the values that you have.

This should work as you expect.

Comment: Why was downvoted my answer? Just to let you know that I tested and its working perfectly.